# How do I avoid duplicate parents in pysimpleGUI tree (Tk tree?)

Tags: tree, tk-toolkit, pysimplegui

Given a list of dot-notation strings, I need to arrange them in a pySiplmpleGUI tree, but I can't figure out how to track the parents correctly. For example, if I have 3 strings:

```
['a.1',
 'a.b.1',
 'a.b.2']
```

I would expect:

```
a
 |_
   1
 |_
   b
   |_
   | 1
   |_
     2
```

What I get is

```
a
 |_
   1
a
 |_
   b
   |_
     1
a
 |_
   b
   |_
     2
```

I would have thought it would use "a" as a parent for everything, but instead each entry is within its own a-level. But all the "a"s have the same keys and are used as the parent for all other entries. My debugger shows they all have the same parent "a" so why wouldn't they be listed under a single "a"?

[image: Debugger Output]

Here's the code with a few more cases in the list to test with:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import PySimpleGUI as sg

treedata = sg.TreeData()

sigs = ['a.1',
 'a.2',
 'a.3',
 'a.b.1',
 'a.b.2',
 'a.b.c.1',
 'a.b.c.4',
 'a.b.d.1',
 'a.b.d.5',
 'a.b.d.6']

for i, val in enumerate(sigs) :     
    separated = val.split(".") # creates list of dot-pathed names
    fullname = '' 
    for f in separated:
         parent=fullname
         if fullname =='':
             fullname=f
         else:
             fullname = fullname+'.'+f #rebuild the name step by step to use as the key
         
         treedata.insert(parent, fullname, f, values=[] );
    
 
layout = [[ sg.Text('File and folder browser Test') ],
          [ sg.Tree(data=treedata, headings=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], auto_size_columns=True, num_rows=20, col0_width=30, key='_TREE_', show_expanded=False,),
            ],
          [ sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]

window = sg.Window('Tree Element Test').Layout(layout)


while True:     # Event Loop
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event in (None, 'Cancel'):
        break
    print(event, values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, but simply needed a little insight from github of pysimplegui. Solution with working code: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/1170#issuecomment-671657177

Comment: GitHub is the place to go for support for this project.